# Why can't I edit multiple dynamic prototypes in UITableView?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, interface-builder

I'm creating a Table View in Interface Builder (Storyboard).  I'd like to have a couple of different Dynamic Prototype cells with different sets of Labels and Images in them and so on, and I can give them different reuseIdentifiers so I can pick which ones I want at runtime.

In Interface Builder, I create several Dynamic Prototype cells in my UITableView, which is controlled by a UITableViewController.

In the first cell, I drag and drop in various views and so on.

In the second cell, IB will not let me drag any views into it?  I can resize the second cell vertically, but can't put anything into it at all, either by dragging into the cell or into the object graph in the left-side bar.

If I copy and paste the first cell, a second Dynamic Prototype will appear with all of the same contents, but I won't be able to modify the copied cell (can't add or move subviews).  However--and this is strange--I can select the constraints and modify their values to resize and shift objects in the second cell.

As a note, running XCode 5-DP3.  Tried restarting it (didn't expect that to help, and it didn't).  Otherwise, unsure what to try, and unsure if I'm doing something very braindead, or if this is a bug I need to report to Apple.

So, am I crazy?  Has anyone experienced this/can anyone recreate this?

EDIT:

After further testing, if I stick a big UIView into the first cell, and then copy that cell, I can edit inside my added view.  (Does this make sense?)  I can't edit anything that lies within the second UITableViewCell, but if it contains a UIView copied over from the first cell, I can put new views into that view and move them around and so on.  Super-strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of posterity, I'm answering my own question:

The way I solved this was to take a UITableViewCell object from the Object library and drag it onto the UITableView.  Sounds simple, right?

The problem I was running into was only if I copied existing dynamic prototypes through Cmd+C & Cmd+V, or by incrementing the number in the Attributes inspector for the table view.  The Storyboard Editor wouldn't allow me to modify those ones.

Dropping in new cells from the Object library let me tweak them all separately.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 5-DP6 solved issues with not abling to resize cell's subviews.